# Email Hosting Service

Tags: email, hosting

Due to my tendency to transform my webservers into a messy playground, I need to move my client's emails into an external server dedicated to that subject. I never worked with a service like this, so I'd like to know recommendations from the community about email hosting companies / services.

Cheers!

Comment: This is basically a shopping question ("what's a good X?"), which is considered off-topic here (because what's good for you and your needs isn't the same thing that's good for me).

Comment: The quality of the review, ways of expression about it, features reviewed, service classification and so on, are the points I'm looking for. Don't take it the wrong way, I'm a web coder.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps for Business

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html

I have recommend this to a few people and they have loved it, if the company is small enough you can use there free service.

There is also MS Office 365

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/office365/online-software.aspx?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=PS_google_MSFT_Brand+Top+Terms_office%20365_Text

These are the 2 that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

fastmail.fm is a pretty solid service.  I don't use their hosted business offering but I've been a personal users for many years.

Also, what the heck are you doing to those web servers?